# Vertically aligning side-by-side images in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, vertical-alignment

**tl;dr:** In any Beamer presentation, how to vertically align images at the **top**?

Consider the following frame:

```
\begin{frame}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig1}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig2}

\end{frame}
```

Imagine fig1 is a long, skinny image, and fig2 is a square:

```
|--|
|  |  |---|
|  |  |   |
|  |  |---|
|--|
```

How to force beamer to output the following? If fig1 is extra long, then it may run off the page and that is OK (perhaps even intentional).

```
|--|  |---|
|  |  |   |
|  |  |---|
|  |
|--|
```

Things I've tried that I couldn't get to work (maybe I'm doing it wrong):

- Figures
- `\begin{frame}[t]`
- `\vfill`
- `\vspace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
[image]

With help of the `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` by which the image baseline is moved to their top:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Both images are aligned at top}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth, height=0.4\textheight, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
        \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```